# CSV DictReader, how to force a part in "" to be read as list not as string

Tags: python, oop, csv

persons.CSV file looks like:

```
Firstname,Surname,Birth Year,Hobby
John,Smith,1990,"tenis,piano"
Andrew,Josh,1988,"surfing,art"
```

I would like that in program hobby will be represented as list not as string. How can I force to that DictReader?

The python code I use look as follows:

```
import csv
class Person(object):
extPerson = []
counter = 0

def __init__(self, **args):
    for k, v in args.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)
    Person.counter += 1
    Person.extPerson.append(self)
def __str__(self):
    s=""
    for k,v in self.__dict__.items():
        s+=k+": "+v+", "
    return s


csvdr = csv.DictReader(open('persons.csv'))


for p  in csvdr:
print p
Person(**p)

for p in Person.extPerson:
print p
print p.Hobby
```

The output looks as follows:

```
{'Birth Year': '1990', 'Hobby': 'tenis,piano', 'Surname': 'Smith', 'Firstname': 'John'}
{'Birth Year': '1988', 'Hobby': 'surfing,art', 'Surname': 'Josh', 'Firstname': 'Andrew'}
Birth Year: 1990, Hobby: tenis,piano, Surname: Smith, Firstname: John, 
tenis,piano
Birth Year: 1988, Hobby: surfing,art, Surname: Josh, Firstname: Andrew, 
surfing,art
```

I would like hobbys being packed in constructor into list:

```
(...)
Birth Year: 1990, Hobby: ['tenis','piano'], Surname: Smith, Firstname: John, 
['tenis', 'piano']
Birth Year: 1988, Hobby: ['surfing','art'], Surname: Josh, Firstname: Andrew, 
['surfing', 'art']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're reading the rows in, you need to `split()` the hobby field:

```
one_row = {'Birth Year': '1990', 'Hobby': 'tenis,piano', 'Surname': 'Smith', 'Firstname': 'John'}
one_row['Hobby'] = one_row['Hobby'].split(',')
one_row
Out[7]: 
{'Birth Year': '1990',
 'Firstname': 'John',
 'Hobby': ['tenis', 'piano'],
 'Surname': 'Smith'}
```

In your current code, this would go here:

```
for p  in csvdr:
    p['Hobby'] = p['Hobby'].split(',')
    print p
    Person(**p)
```

Your current `__str__` method won't work with the lists, but you only need a small change to fix that- you convert the list values to strings using `str`, and the string values are unaffected:

```
def __str__(self):
    s=""
    for k,v in self.__dict__.items():
        s += k + ": " + str(v) + ", "
    return s
```

Comment: By appling yout proposal I get: TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

Comment: In your constructor, or in your `__str__` method? Because it doesn't look like your `__str__` method will deal with the lists, even though that's the data format you want. `s+=k+": "+ str(v) +", "` might fix it, but it's kind of a separate issue.

Comment: I do not think about workaround for beautiful prints. Thats not a problem. I want to have desired data structure in my OO-world. Read: build in constructor as desired: hobbys stored in list.

Comment: Does splitting the `Hobby` field work for you? I'm not sure where the issue is if you're still having problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyDictReader(csv.DictReader):
    def next(self):
        if self.line_num == 0:
            # Used only for its side effect.
            self.fieldnames
        row = self.reader.next()
        self.line_num = self.reader.line_num

        # unlike the basic reader, we prefer not to return blanks,
        # because we will typically wind up with a dict full of None
        # values
        while row == []:
            row = self.reader.next()
        row = map(lambda x:x.split(",") if "," in x else x,row)
        d = dict(zip(self.fieldnames, row))
        lf = len(self.fieldnames)
        lr = len(row)
        if lf < lr:
            d[self.restkey] = row[lf:]
        elif lf > lr:
            for key in self.fieldnames[lr:]:
                d[key] = self.restval
        return d
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it as follows. Marius your answer was a kind of hint.

```
for p  in csvdr:
    #p["Hobby"] = p["Hobby"].split(',') not working, TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

    l=p["Hobby"].split(',') #this will be list
    p["Hobby"]=l #let key show on value being list
    print p
    Person(**p)
```

We can make sure:

```
for p in Person.extPerson:
    print p
    print p.Hobby
    print type(p.Hobby)
```

results in:

```
{'Birth Year': '1990', 'Hobby': ['tenis', 'piano'], 'Surname': 'Smith', 'Firstname': 'John'}
{'Birth Year': '1988', 'Hobby': ['surfing', 'art'], 'Surname': 'Josh', 'Firstname': 'Andrew'}
Birth Year: 1990, Hobby: ['tenis', 'piano']Surname: Smith, Firstname: John, 
['tenis', 'piano']
<type 'list'>
Birth Year: 1988, Hobby: ['surfing', 'art']Surname: Josh, Firstname: Andrew, 
['surfing', 'art']
<type 'list'>
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

by the way **str** needed modification with checking type, and appropriately treating list:

```
def __str__(self):
    s=""
    for k,v in self.__dict__.items():
        if type(v) is not list:
            s+=k+": "+v+", "
        else:
            s+=k+": "+str(v)    
    return s
```

**I am new to python, so ANY suggestions for better code practice will be appreciated.**

Comment: The `__str__` method could be a lot simpler, you can just call `str()` on all values, even if they're already strings. See my answer.

Comment: corrected - noticed later - being earlier focused on problem with spliting and assigning to list. THANKS ANYWAY!